# CTE query With 2 conditions not working?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I was born in 1978/12/22

I wanted a query (in CTE!) to display me all my birthdays (datepart day = 22)

```
declare @t0 datetime  = '1978/12/22';
declare @t1 datetime  = getdate();


 with CTEE (val,day1)
AS
(
    SELECT @t0,DATEPART(day,@t0)
    UNION   all
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,val) , DATEPART(day,day1) from  ctee where( DATEADD(day,1,val) <=@t1)   and DATEPART(day,day1)=22
)
select val,day1 from CTEE OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20000)
```

How ever this seems to return me 1 row ( **why**???)

`If I remove` `and DATEPART(day,day1)=22` so it gives me all the days im alive.

The solution I found is this:

```
  declare @t0 datetime  = '1978/12/22';
    declare @t1 datetime  = getdate();


     with CTEE (val,day1)
    AS
    (
        SELECT @t0,DATEPART(day,@t0)
        UNION   all
        SELECT DATEADD(day,1,val) , DATEPART(day,day1) from  ctee where( DATEADD(day,1,val) <=@t1)  

    )
    select val,day1 from CTEE where day1=22  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20000)
```

But my question is **why** in the first query it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the second record is `1978-12-23`.

That doesn't meet the `DATEPART(day,day1)=22` condition, so that recursive step returns no results, this terminates the recursion as documented in [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

> **The termination check is implicit; recursion stops when no rows are
>   returned from the previous invocation.**

Comment: Ive bolded it ! thanks a lot. I didnt know that. I thought only when he finishes through all the select

Comment: @RoyiNamir - From BOL [The termination check is implicit; recursion stops when no rows are returned from the previous invocation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - [Books On Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx)!